# Which Primary ID should i use in task table

Tags: mysql

You will see my question is very simple but i dont know what is the better way to index an entry. In a very simplified way, i have four tables 'cars', 'companies', 'companyCars' and 'companyTasks'.

```
'Table cars
carid INT PRIMARY
carname TINYTEXT

'Table companies
compid INT PRIMARY
compName TINYTEXT

'Table companyCars
compcarid INT PRIMARY
compid INT
carid INT

'Table companyTasks
taskid INT PRIMARY
compid
carid INT
taskDescr TEXT
...
```

What is the better way to get a relation to my cars. In the companyTasks Table is it better to go over the companyCars Table (and so with the compcarid) or is it better to have (in a direct way) the carid in the companyTasks Table.

The problem is, that only the cars which are with the companyCars Table related to a company, are allowed to be used in the companyTasks table.

Hope you can help me finding the best way.

seehma

Comment: Presumably cars can only ever belong to one company at a time, so why not just have one table (cars), with a nullable column identifying to which company (if any) a given car belongs.

Answer (score 1):

One option I would explore:

if the `companyCars` table is the implementation of a "relationship" rather than an "entity", I would consider making the PRIMARY KEY of that table a composite key... `(compid, carid)`.

If there's some reason you need the PRIMARY KEY to be the simple integer `compcarid` column, then at least put a UNIQUE constraint (unique index) on `(compid,carid)`.

Either way, the foreign key constraint from `companyTasks` can reference the composite key.

```
  CONSTRAINT FK_companyTasks_companyCars  
  FOREIGN KEY (compid, carid)
  REFERENCES `companyCars` (compid, carid)
```

---

This approach allows the database to enforce the stated requirement/specification...

> only the cars which are with the companyCars Table related to a company, are allowed to be used in the companyTasks table.

---

I'm not sure this answered the question you were asking.

The normative pattern is for a foreign key to reference a primary key. But MySQL allows a foreign key to reference a column (or set of columns) which is not the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go over the companyCars Table because it ensures that no "wrong" car finds it's way into the companyTasks. But if you don't need that kind of safety, using the direct way is just fine as well.